# How do I recieve values from Config page to my C Pebble code?

Tags: pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js, clay

I have been following the Pebble Clay Config process but am stuck. I want to be able to chnage temp value from C to F, I have the code to do this but whenever I send the information from the clay config page back to pebble it does not seem to be able to read it? I keep getting an appfault error. That's all it says.

Also it uses Clay Configuration

Link to the whole code is [here](https://github.com/RuebenBurrows/weathertime).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have seen the comprehensive [pebble/clay](https://github.com/pebble/clay) help pages.

You should also add the message keys you specified in `config.js` in **SETTINGS** -> **PEBBLEKIT JS MESSAGE KEYS** in CloudPebble.

You can then read the key values in C code from the message you receive using the identifier `MESSAGE_KEY_TempCond`.

There are many simple examples of this on [GitHub](http://github.com).